# Spring boot gradle - getting No signature of method: .bootJar() is applicable for argument types

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

I am upgrading spring boot and gradle version in spring boot batch application as below,

**spring boot** - 2.3.3.RELEASE to 2.6.7

**gradle** - 6.6 to 7.4.2

while building project getting below error

```
Build file '/Users/abcuser/Documents/PROJECT/newbatch/build.gradle' line: 29

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'newbatch'.
> No signature of method: build_8555gqf06rjal4kabfn0v4b5b.bootJar() is applicable for argument types: (build_8555gqf06rjal4kabfn0v4b5b$_run_closure2) values: [build_8555gqf06rjal4kabfn0v4b5b$_run_closure2@3a423977]
```

**build.gradle** is as below

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.6.7'
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version "${springBootVersion}"
}

bootJar {
    launchScript {
        properties 'mode': 'service'
        properties 'logFolder': 'logs/'
        properties 'logFilename': 'stdout'
        properties 'pidFolder': 'run/'
        properties 'pidFilename': "${archiveBaseName.get()}.pid"
    }
    archiveFileName = "${archiveBaseName.get()}.${archiveExtension.get()}"
    mainClassName('jp.co.abc.BatchApplication')
}
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties** is as below

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.2-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

Answer (score 1):

After modifying **build.gradle** code like below, not getting same error.

```
tasks.named("bootJar") {
    launchScript {
        properties 'mode': 'service'
        properties 'logFolder': 'logs/'
        properties 'logFilename': 'stdout'
        properties 'pidFolder': 'run/'
        properties 'pidFilename': "${archiveBaseName.get()}.pid"
    }
    archiveFileName = "${archiveBaseName.get()}.${archiveExtension.get()}"
    mainClass = 'jp.co.rakuten.english.ReduBatchApplication'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An addition to @Sam's answer. I did it this way:

```
bootJar {
    mainClass = "jp.co.abc.BatchApplication"
}
```